# Is there a C# alternative to Java's vararg parameters?

Tags: c#

I have worked on Java and new to .Net technology

Is it possible to declare a function in C# which accepts variable input parameters

Is there any C# syntax similar to the following Java syntax?

```
void f1(String... a)
```

Answer (score 177):

Yes, C# has an equivalent of varargs parameters. They're called [*parameter arrays*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx), and introduced with the `params` modifier:

```
public void Foo(int x, params string[] values)
```

Then call it with:

```
Foo(10, "hello", "there");
```

Just as with Java, it's only the last parameter which can vary like this. Note that (as with Java) a parameter of `params object[] objects` can easily cause confusion, as you need to remember whether a single argument of type `object[]` is meant to be wrapped again or not. Likewise for any nullable type, you need to remember whether a single argument of `null` will be treated as an array reference or a single array element. (I *think* the compiler only creates the array if it has to, but I tend to write code which avoids me having to remember that.)

Comment: +1, though I would mention that (as with pretty much any other language feature), this should not be abused.

Comment: @HighCore: If you're going to mention it about pretty much any other language feature, it's probably not worth mentioning :)

Comment: @hvd: Given that the OP appears to be a beginner, I'd rather not go into named arguments, optional parameters etc here. I see the point that you're trying to make, but I think it would add more confusion than light at the moment.

Answer (score 40):

Have a look at [params (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a
>   variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the
>   specified type. You also can send no arguments.
>
> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a
>   method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a
>   method declaration.

As shown in the example the method is declared as

```
public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and used as

```
UseParams(1, 2, 3, 4);
```