# Calculate with X number of variables

Tags: c#, variables

I am wondering how I could make a calculation (in this case, calculating the average) with a variable number of variables / fields in C#?
I could write an if case for each number of variables but I bet there is a better way for it, right?
The bad way would like this:

```
if (numberOfFields == 4)
   (field1 + field2 + field3 + field4) / 4;
if (numberOfFields == 5)
   (field1 + field2 + field3 + field4 + field5) / 5;
.
.
.
```

Greetings!

Comment: [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a C# alternative to Java's vararg parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194849/is-there-a-c-sharp-alternative-to-javas-vararg-parameters)

Comment: Any time you have variable names like X1, X2, X3, etc. then what you want is an array or collection of some kind.  In C#, you might be looking for a `List<int>`.

Comment: Let us say that for whatever reason you cannot have a field of type array or other collection. We could do this with reflections. Is that what you want? I would expect you to be familiar with arrays before being familiar with reflection. So, sorry if I misjudged that. You are going to need arrays anyway, see [Get field values from a simple class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649355/402022).

Comment: Arrays, right. This way it works. So simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize your variables (`field1, field2...`) into a *collection*, say, array (you can well use `List<T>` and many other collections):

```
 //TODO: put the right type here
 double[] array = new double[] {
   field1,
   field2,
   field3,
   field4,
   field5,
   ... 
 };
```

Then query with a help of *LInq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 var average = array
   .Take(numberOfFields)
   .Average();
```

Comment: Ugh, what about `List<double>`, then you can add/remove as needed...

Comment: @zaggler: `List<double>` will do as well as many other collections